# Prove that for all points $q$ and $p$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$,$\rho(p,q) :L^2(C^n)\Longrightarrow L^2(C^n)$ is a unitary operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

I provide some context to the problem

We identify points in $\mathbb{R^n}$x$\mathbb{R^n}$ with points in $\mathbb{C^n}$ via the identification

$\mathbb{R^n}$x$\mathbb{R^n}\ni(q,p)\longleftrightarrow q+ip\in\mathbb{C^n}$.

I define $\rho(p,q)$ as follows,
Let $p$ and $q$ be points in $\mathbb{R^n}$, and let $f$ be a measurable functions on $\mathbb{R^n}$,We define the function $\rho(p,q)f$ on $\mathbb{R^n}$ by

$(\rho(p,q)f)(x)=e^{iq.x+1/2ip.q}f(x+p)$,$x\in\mathbb{R^n}$

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions on $S$(Swartz functions).Then we define the Fourier-Wigner Transform $V(f,g)$ on $f$ and $g$ on $\mathbb{R^n}$ to be the function on $\mathbb{R^n}$x$\mathbb{R^n}$ by

$V(f,g)(q,p)$=$(2\pi)^{-n/2}(\rho(p,q)f,g)(x)$ where $q,p\in\mathbb{R^n}$

Please I need some assistance in solving this problem?

Forgive me if my latex is unreadable,Im just a beginner

Comment: Thanks for working with LaTex.  You did pretty well!